# Verizon contract fulfilled, yet no other carrier will touch my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, meid

Several people are saying on this site and other sites that they have been able to get service for their Verizon iPhone 4 (with contract fulfilled already) on either Straight Talk or Page Plus.  But when I call both companies, they say they can not activate any Verizon iPhones.

Why the contradictory info?  How can I take my money (less of it hopefully) elsewhere? I  barely even use the thing, so spending the $80 plus a month with Verizon is not acceptable any more (and my 2 year contract is up).

Comment: You use the word "activate" which could be the initial activation of the hardware into a cell network or the activation of the device through iTunes or over the air after an OS restore. Are you using that word explicitly (as no other career does any of those "activations") or does it mean they will not enter the MEID for your phone into their network?

Comment: and Verizon did not tell you that when your were buying it.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4 built for Verizon's network is a CDMA-only device that is not capable of operating on a GSM network that requires a SIM card, such as StraightTalk (which uses T-Mobile's network). That said, Page Plus operates on Verizon so there shouldn't be any impediment assuming you've had the phone unlocked already.

[This thread](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1760615-Verizon-iPhone-4-on-Page-Plus) indicates that Page Plus phone reps are hit-or-miss when it comes to allowing you to use an iPhone. About halfway down the page there are steps for doing so online, thereby avoiding the troublesome CSRs.

> 1. Activate online. This costs $10.
> 2. Wait (10) minutes, then dial *22890. This will program the iPhone 4 and takes about 30 seconds.
> 3. Dial 611, "Welcome to PPC"
> 4. Use any third party like Pinzoo or CallingMart to buy a calling package & Pin. PPC didn't let me use PayPal.